# C++ Pointer Issues - Mangled Data

Tags: arduino-uno, c++, pointer

I am having trouble getting my head around pointers in C++, specifically how they behave when passed around or used within objects. As far as my understanding goes as long as pointers, or more specifically values/objects pointed *to* - do not go out of scope, I should be able to use that pointer.

I have been playing around with some test code on my Arduino Uno and I am bumping into behaviour I cannot explain.

I have read rather a lot on the topic of pointers in C++ and thought I had a good grasp of it. However, practice doesn't seem to match the theory in my head. I don't know if this is a lack of understanding or if the Arduino platform has idiosyncrasies that I am not aware of.

In my test code I have created two classes, `Alpha` and `Beta`. Alpha simply holds a C-type string in a member variable called `alpha`. `Beta` is designed to hold two `Alpha` instances in an array*.

*While this is "toy" code, the general structure mirrors my actual project. I have used this toy code as it more succinctly describes the set up and the issue I am facing.

**pointers.h**

```
#import "Arduino.h"
class Alpha {
    private:
        char alpha[20];
    public:
        Alpha();
        ~Alpha();
        char* getAlpha(char* s, int size=20);
        void setAlpha(char* value, int size=20);
        void debug();
};

class Beta {
    private:
        Alpha** alphas;
    public:
        Beta();
        ~Beta();
        Alpha* getAlpha(int index);
        void setAlpha(Alpha* alpha, int index);
        void doStuffWithAlpha(int index);
};
```

**pointers.cpp**

```
#import "pointers.h"

Alpha::Alpha() {
    setAlpha("Initial");
}

Alpha::~Alpha() {}

char* Alpha::getAlpha(char* s, int size/*=20*/) {
    *s = *alpha;
    return s; //return not strictly needed here since s is passed in
}

void Alpha::setAlpha(char* value, int size/*=20*/) {
    strncpy(alpha, value, size-1);
    alpha[size-1] = '\0';
}

void Alpha::debug() {
    Serial.println(alpha);
}


Beta::Beta() {
    alphas = new Alpha*[2];
}

Beta::~Beta() {}

Alpha* Beta::getAlpha(int index) {
    return alphas[index];
}

void Beta::setAlpha(Alpha* alpha, int index) {
    alphas[index] = alpha;
}

void Beta::doStuffWithAlpha(int index) {
    Alpha* alpha = getAlpha(index);
    /* Alpha* alpha = alphas[index]; */ //This doesn't work either - same outcome.
    alpha->debug();
}
```

**sketch.ino**

```
#import "pointers.h"
Alpha a1;
Alpha a2;
Beta b1;

void setup() {
    Serial.begin(9600);
    Serial.println("SETUP()");
    Serial.println();

    a1 = Alpha();
    a1.setAlpha("Hello");

    Serial.println("----- a1.debug -----");
    Serial.println("Expected: Hello");
    Serial.print("Actual: "); a1.debug();
    Serial.println();

    a2 = Alpha();
    a2.setAlpha("Goodbye");

    Serial.println("----- a2.debug -----");
    Serial.println("Expected: Goodbye");
    Serial.print("Actual: "); a2.debug();
    Serial.println();

    Beta b1 = Beta();
    b1.setAlpha(&a1, 0);
    b1.setAlpha(&a2, 1);

    Serial.println("----- b1.doStuffWithAlpha -----");
    Serial.println("Expected: Hello");
    Serial.print("Actual: "); b1.doStuffWithAlpha(0);
    Serial.println("Expected: Goodbye");
    Serial.print("Actual: "); b1.doStuffWithAlpha(1);
    Serial.println();
}

void loop() {
    Serial.println("LOOP()");
    Serial.println();

    Serial.println("----- a1.debug -----");
    Serial.println("Expected: Hello");
    Serial.print("Actual: "); a1.debug();
    Serial.println();

    Serial.println("----- b1.doStuffWithAlpha(0) ------");
    Serial.println("Expected: Hello");
    Serial.print("Actual: "); b1.doStuffWithAlpha(0);
    Serial.println();

    Serial.println("----- a2.debug -----");
    Serial.println("Expected: Goodbye");
    Serial.print("Actual:   "); a2.debug();
    Serial.println();

    Serial.println("----- b1.doStuffWithAlpha(1) ------");
    Serial.println("Expected: Goodbye");
    Serial.print("Actual:   "); b1.doStuffWithAlpha(1);
    Serial.println();

    delay(10000);
}
```

This sketch is quite straight-forward. It creates 2 `Alpha` objects and a `Beta` object and passes the two Alphas into Beta. The myriad `Serial.print()` statements produces the output below.

**output**

```
SETUP()

----- a1.debug -----
Expected: Hello
Actual:   Hello

----- a2.debug -----
Expected: Goodbye
Actual:   Goodbye

----- b1.doStuffWithAlpha -----
Expected: Hello
Actual:   Hello

Expected: Goodbye
Actual:   Goodbye

//everything is fine up to this point...

LOOP()

----- a1.debug -----
Expected: Hello
Actual:   Hello

----- b1.doStuffWithAlpha(0) ------
Expected: Hello
Actual:   CÃoçëyc=Lä^ÜŽYw¸Nv†Ý¿  //uh oh...

----- a2.debug -----
Expected: Goodbye
Actual:   Goodbye

----- b1.doStuffWithAlpha(1) ------
Expected: Goodbye
Actual:   ÿß/ï //uh oh again...
```

Everything works as expected when running `a1` or `a2.debug()` or `b1.doStuffWithAlpha()` in the `setup()` function.

The result of `a1.debug()` and `a2.debug()` works as expected in the `loop()` function.

The issue, as you can see, is when running `b1.doStuffWithAlpha(0)` or `b1.doStuffWithAlpha(1)`. The output is usually junk, which suggests to me the pointer has been mangled and points in the wrong place.

I don't understand what is happening between the transition from `setup()` to `loop()`. At first I thought the issue was the "Hello" and "Goodbye" strings going out of scope, but `Alpha::setAlpha()` makes a copy of the C-string. Also, accessing `Alpha::debug()` in `loop()` works, as shown above.

I have tried variations on the above code, such as using a struct or an int for `alpha` instead of a C-string and the results are the same: Mangled values.

Have I done something obviously silly that my scant C++ experience hasn't picked up on, or is there some fundamental Arduino shenanigans at play?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Problem is local shadow variable `b1` in setup() function declared as `Beta b1 = Beta();`. In `loop()` is considered uninitialized global variable `b1`.

Comment: I agree that is probably the problem. Also in your destructor for Beta you should `delete` the pointers you allocate in the constructor. I'm not wildly keen on doing `new` in a constructor at static scope either because of the [static initialization order fiasco](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/static-init-order.html).

Comment: @TMa I can't believe I missed that! I must have been looking at my own code for too long! @NickGammon I agree that I should have a destructor, it was left out for just this example. Regarding the use of `new` in a constructor, how else would I do it? Reading the link you gave, the initialisation fiasco only affects classes/types declared in different compilation units. My code has both classes defined in the same file.

Comment: If the project ever gets large enough that you have more than one compilation unit, it may affect you. What you can do is have a `begin` method which is called from `setup` (eg. like Serial). Alternatively (or as well) you could set the pointers to NULL in the constructor (which is safe) and then allocate them with `new` when they are needed.